# Mail.app signature attached mac

Tags: mail.app, signature

I've added a signature in Mail.app and it works fine. It's a basic HTML table with images that are hosted and never attached directly.

The problem is that when I attach a file (not images), the signature becomes an attachment file (.html) and it isn't displayed in the mail once the receiver reads it.

I've tried to edit the signature directly from the *.mailsignature file with the same result.

Does someone have any clue?